# Countability and Uncountability of Computer Programs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computability

I'm having trouble with countability and uncountability. I'm stuck on a homework question without an idea how to approach it.

Argue the following:

- The set of computer programs in any language must be at most countably infinite. What do
  we know about computer programs?
- For a given programming language, most real numbers cannot be computed as the
  (potentially infinite) output of any program.

Anything would be of help!

Comment: It's hard to know how to help without knowing what you know. Perhaps a slightly more tractable variant: can you show that the set of all finite strings of text in a given alphabet is countable? You can do so by showing you can encode each string of text as a natural number in such a way that distinct strings are encoded by distinct natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Each program is a finite sequence of a finite number of symbols.
Each program is a finite sequence of a finite number of operations. 
There are an finite number of programs of length n.
Add the number of all these groups of programs
to conclude there are denumberable many programs.

As each program has a finite output, all together all
the possible programs has denumberable many outputs.

Thus, most of the real numbers are beyond human and machine reach.

Comment: The argument is wrong : you can't just "add the number of all these groups". One has to be carefull when dealing with infinite sets.

Comment: Denumberable  x denumberable = denumberable

Comment: @OlivierRoche.  It is well know that denumberable x denumberable = denumberable.

Answer (score 0):

A language is a set of words, which are themselves finite sequences of elements of some alphabet, say $\Sigma$. I assume that the alphabet $\Sigma$ is finite (it has to be finite or countable otherwise otherwise claim 1 is wrong). Let's assume that $\Sigma \neq \emptyset$ (I like alphabets that actually allow you to write something, don't you?).

Let $\Sigma^*$ be the set of words using alphabet $\Sigma$. $\Sigma^*$ is at most countable since it is a countable union of finite sets :

$$\Sigma^* = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \Sigma^n$$

Hence, there are at most countably many computer programs using alphabet $\Sigma$.

There are uncountably many real numbers (cf [Cantor's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument)), and only countably many programs. Hence, most of the real numbers can't be written by computer programs using a given finite alphabet.

Comment: I find this enlightening. I assume its possible to talk about computer programs using the turning machines as a formalism of "program"?

Comment: @user512716 This is what one usually does, yes. But I just worked with the assumption that a program is a finite sequence of symbols.